# node ssh2 shell unable to run apt-get install on remote machine

Tags: node.js

I'm doing a program in node.js to deploy my code from git to a server (Digital Ocean). I'm connecting to the server via ssh2 module and running commands via shell, like bellow:

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.shell(function(err, stream) {

    if (err) throw err;

    stream.on('close', function() {

      console.log('Stream :: close');
      conn.end();

    }).on('data', function(data) {

      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);

    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {

      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);

    });

    stream.end('sudo apt-get update -y\nsudo apt-get install -y build-essential\nexit\n');
 });
}).connect({
  host: 'x.x.x.x',
  port: 22,
  username: 'yyy',
  privateKey: 'zzz'
});
```

The command "apt-get update" works fine, but the command "apt-get install build-essential" (I have tried to install other programs, like vim and curl) seems to freeze the stream on output's last line. 
I think it can be caused by the prompt "Y/n" of the apt-get, but I couldn't find a workaround for it. Someone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `\n`with `&&`:

```
stream.end('sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y build-essential && exit');
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I just added a '\n' on the end of your line. Thank you!!

Comment: Also you should be able to use `exec()` instead of `shell()` to more easily parse output and to avoid having to send LF.